# Outlook 2010 automatic profile setup not working on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: exchange-2013, windows-10, outlook-2010

on my domain the new Windows 10 Pro machines are not setting up the Outlook 2010 profile automatically. Users are bring prompted for all the server information in the Outlook 2010 startup wizard (configure email Y/N, Name, Email, Password, etc).

On the older Window 7 Pro machines, the Outlook 2010 startup for the first time the user was only prompted with Confirm Name & Initial, they just needed to click ok and their email was ready to go.

Both computers are in the same OU with the same GPO applied.

Domain is Window 2008 R2 at the highest forest & domain level

Exchange is 2013

Any help as to why this isn't working on Windows 10 would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to test autoconfiguration through autoconfiguration tool of outlook. Open outlook go on the icon of outlook (near the clock) hold control, right click and test autoconfiguration. There after you put the username and password should show the xml file with settings that outlooks fetch from the server ([Small Guide](https://kb.intermedia.net/article/2150)). It sounds like dns issue though make sure the win 10 pcs are joined to the domain and can ping on server's fqdn.